# How to set 0 and set 1 when check box is unselected or selected in Angular 9?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have two check boxes that works like radio buttons. I want to set the value as 1 for first check box when it is checked or 0 when it is unselected. Similarly, I want to set the value as 2 for second check box when it is checked or 0 when it is unselected.

My ts code:

```
 selectMRSABox(e) {
        if (e.target.id === 'mrsa_All') {
            this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_AllSpecimens = true;
            this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_BloodOnly = false;
        } else {
            this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_BloodOnly = true;
            this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_AllSpecimens = false;
        }

    }
```

.html file

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mrsa_All" (change)="selectMRSABox($event)" [checked]="this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_AllSpecimens">
<input type="checkbox" id="mrsa_Blood" (change)="selectMRSABox($event)" [checked]="this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_BloodOnly">
```

Comment: can you check the link now? I think it is fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you. To achieve what you desire you can use `ngModel` and `ngModelChange`. Here is my sample code and stackblitz link given below=>

**HTML:**

```
CH One:<input text="" type="checkbox" id="mrsa_All" (ngModelChange)="selectMRSABox($event,'mrsa_All')" [(ngModel)]="this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_AllSpecimens">
{{this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_AllSpecimensNumber}}
<br>
CH Two:<input type="checkbox" id="mrsa_Blood" (ngModelChange)="selectMRSABox($event,'mrsa_Blood')" [(ngModel)]="this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_BloodOnly"> 
{{this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_BloodOnlyNumber}}
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.scss' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
specimenTypeOrganismStatus: SpecimenTypeOrganismStatus;
  theCheckbox:any;
  constructor() {
  this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus=new SpecimenTypeOrganismStatus();
  }
 
  selectMRSABox($event,name){
        if (name === 'mrsa_All') {
            //this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_AllSpecimens = true;
            this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_AllSpecimensNumber=1;
             this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_BloodOnlyNumber=0;
            this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_BloodOnly = false;
        } else if(name === 'mrsa_Blood'){
            //this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_BloodOnly = true;
            this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_AllSpecimensNumber=0;
            this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_BloodOnlyNumber=1;
            this.specimenTypeOrganismStatus.mrsa_AllSpecimens = false;
        }
  }
}
export class SpecimenTypeOrganismStatus{
  mrsa_AllSpecimens: boolean ;
  mrsa_AllSpecimensNumber: number ;
  mrsa_BloodOnly: boolean ;
  mrsa_BloodOnlyNumber: number ;
}
```

**NOTE:** Please check the link => [STACKBLITZ SAMPLE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodel-checkbox-z7rdye?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Hi SJNF, I checked in stackblitz link that you gave. It says some import error

Comment: ok wait. some thing went wrong. I will fix it and get back to you.

Comment: @vishnu can you check the link now? I think it is fine now.

Comment: Thank you SJNF it works, but I want the value 1 when it is checked and 0 when we uncheck. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: @vishnu of course it is quite possible. can you tell me in which variable you want to set 0 or 1?

Comment: I want to save it in any variable like 'checkStatus'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229505/discussion-between-sjnf-and-vishnu).

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your input type

(change)="status = $event.target.checked ? 1: 0"

Comment: Hi should I create a variable and name it 'status' in the ts file.

Comment: @vishnu Yes create a variable in ts